# Failed to add aws-sdk-rust to dependency within cargo.toml

Tags: rust, openssl, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-rust

I'm build a Rust project integrating with AWS.
I'm going to use `aws-sdk-rust` crate and added it into `cargo.toml`.
But I faced an issue, and wasn't able to fix it.

Here's the issue content.

error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl v0.9.24`
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/home/simon/Documents/Meta/Binarite/target/debug/build/openssl-7e671383bd034c48/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at /home/simon/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-0.9.24/build.rs:16:14:
Unable to detect OpenSSL version
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

Here's what I tried to solve this.

- sudo apt install pkg-config
- sudo apt install libssl-dev
- sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
- manually get openssl library sources and build it myself https://agryaznov.com/guides/2019/05/20/substrate-install.html#openssl

But all above does not work. How to fix this?